# Is the use of logistic regression with 'ordered entry of variables' in this paper statistically meaningful?

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm reading [a paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29106728/) which says:

> In performing the logistic regression analyses, **the order of entry of predictor variables was guided by our theoretical rationale and our major hypotheses**. In each analysis, control variables reflective of selection effects (income-to-needs ratio, beliefs about the benefits of maternal employment) were entered into the regression equation first, and then the main effect of a mother or child characteristic was tested. The main effect of a child-care variable was tested next, and then the interaction between (i.e., the product of) the mother/child variable and the child-care variable.

I don't understand what's happening here. I *think* they are running three separate logistic regressions, each with more predictors, and using different regressions to test the significance of different terms. **Is this statistically meaningful?** What advantage is there to this approach, compared to just throwing all the variables into a single logistic regression?

NB There are actually 5 mother/child vars & 5 childcare vars -- but they are running 25 separate analyses, looking at each possible pair, so only look at one variable of each kind in each analysis.

Comment: You might find it helpful to compare and contrast this method with [stepwise regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stepwise+regression).

Comment: There's a lot of testing going on.  It would be preferable to use subject-matter guidance to completely pre-specify a flexible model.  Outside knowledge, such as knowledge that interaction effects are smaller than main effects, can be brought using Bayesian priors.